# Adonis.js give an error when try to run adonis serve --dev command

Tags: database, adonis.js

Adonis.js give an error when try to run `adonis serve --dev` command

This is the error when I am trying to run command in backend:

```
balveer@balveer-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/Downloads/test/blogbackend$ adonis serve --dev

 SERVER STARTED 
> Watching files for changes...


SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<<'


1 anonymous
  /home/balveer/Downloads/test/blogbackend/node_modules/require-all/index.js:56

2 requireAll
  /home/balveer/Downloads/test/blogbackend/node_modules/require-all/index.js:34

3 Config.syncWithFileSystem
  /home/balveer/Downloads/test/blogbackend/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/src/Config/index.js:49

Application crashed, make sure to kill all related running process, fix the issue and re-run the app
```

[image: error when run adonis serve --dev]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error appears when importing the `/config/*.js` configuration files.

Try to check these different files. The `<<` character causes problems.

Comment: any errors in config/* folder will not allows to start server.js