# adonis serve won't work and say unexpected token {

Tags: adonis.js

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59351119/adonis-js-give-an-error-when-try-to-run-adonis-serve-dev-command) when searching google and the error I have is pretty similar but it is not the same, mine is Syntax Error: Unexpected token **{** after doing adonis serve --dev

I installed npm and nodejs 8 under debian 9, I hope someone will have an idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this link's instructions : https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/installation#creating-a-new-project
to solve the problem. I had to update to nodejs 14 and now to start adonis it is **node serve**